# VB.NET finding text between two words in a string

Tags: vb.net, string, sorting

so I'm having trouble finding the code for a feature I'm adding in a program I'm developing in Visual Basic. Currently it sorts through text files, for example logs generated by certain programs, and displays all lines in that file containing a string it's given. I'd like to be able to add the function of being able to choose to cut out certain parts of the displayed line and only show the information I need, for example: only print the part of the line after string1, before string 2, or between the two strings. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It would be a good idea to post the code you are currently working on to show how you are going about it. These forums tend to work best if you show you are trying to do it yourself but running into problems..

Comment: @Tharokir  since your question is unclear and no code, i made a guess `strLine.Replace("cut out certain parts of the displayed line", "show the information I need")`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `.IndexOf` and the `Strings.Mid` functions to search your string and crop out the wanted part:

```
    Dim sSource As String = "Hi my name is Homer Simpson." 'String that is being searched
    Dim sDelimStart As String = "my" 'First delimiting word
    Dim sDelimEnd As String = "Simpson" 'Second delimiting word
    Dim nIndexStart As Integer = sSource.IndexOf(sDelimStart) 'Find the first occurrence of f1
    Dim nIndexEnd As Integer = sSource.IndexOf(sDelimEnd) 'Find the first occurrence of f2

    If nIndexStart > -1 AndAlso nIndexEnd > -1 Then '-1 means the word was not found.
        Dim res As String = Strings.Mid(sSource, nIndexStart + sDelimStart.Length + 1, nIndexEnd - nIndexStart - sDelimStart.Length) 'Crop the text between
        MessageBox.Show(res) 'Display
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("One or both of the delimiting words were not found!")
    End If
```

This will search the string you input (`sSource`) for the occurances of the two words `sDelimStart` and `sDelimEnd` and then use `Strings.Mid` to crop out the parts in between the two words. You need to include the length of `sDelimStart`, because `.IndexOf` will return the start of the word.